# Saveas not working for any file type in Powerbuilder 12.5 when running exe

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a very small PB 12.5 (2511) application, when I run the lds_test.SaveAs from within the IDE, it saves with no issues (xls, csv, txt).

When I create an exe and run it on another pc or the pc I have PB installed, the Saveas returns 1 but no file is saved, no file type works.

So it seems it has something to do with the way I'm creating the exe?  I currently have it set up as follows:

PCODE, Full Build
In Library tab no PBD's are checked off, just list my pbl along with the pfc libraries.

I've installed and ran the run time packager thinking that had something to do with it but still having the issue.  I've wasted tons of time on this and really need some help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty good chance the problem is that the DataWindow object isn't being included in the deployment. When you build an EXE without PBDs, PB tries to include only referenced objects, not including object names in strings. This often excludes DataWindows that you need.

Easiest solution is just to check all PBDs, and you're done. If you're set on a single EXE, the native approach is to create a PBR to force DataWindow objects' inclusion (IME the PBR doesn't work for all object types). If you are willing to go third party to make it easier, I'll point out that PBL Peeper has a "report" (PBR Builder Plus http://www.techno-kitten.com/PBL_Peeper/Online_Manual/Reports_Page/reports_page.html) that helps you create a single EXE deployment (no PBDs) while forcing the inclusion of all necessary objects.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I included all the pbd's, everything is working fine.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Terry is correct, you need a .pbr file to make sure all DataWindow objects are included. This is a common issue with small apps. If a PBD is created for a library, all objects are included. Any libraries that have their objects included in the .exe file will need a .pbr to force inclusion of unreferenced DataWindows.